# apt-file vs apt-cache

Tags: debian, apt

I've known about `apt-cache` for quite some time, but only yesterday stumbled on `apt-file`.

My question is, given this kind of output from the two...

```
ttsiod@avalon ~
$ apt-cache search setxkb
x11-xkb-utils - X11 XKB utilities
xfce4-xkb-plugin - xkb layout switch plugin for the Xfce4 panel

ttsiod@avalon ~
$ apt-file find setxkb
fish: /usr/share/fish/completions/setxkbmap.fish
fish: /usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_complete_setxkbmap.fish
x11-xkb-utils: /usr/bin/setxkbmap
x11-xkb-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.gz
xmanpages-ja: /usr/share/man/ja/man1/setxkbmap.1.gz
zsh: /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/X/_setxkbmap
zsh-beta: /usr/share/zsh-beta/functions/Completion/X/_setxkbmap
zsh-common: /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/X/_setxkbmap
```

...why would one bother with apt-cache? Isn't apt-file superior in every way?

I am probably missing something.

**EDIT**: The reason I am asking is because apt-file reported MORE packages than apt-cache. I only use apt-cache for the use case *"I need tool/manpage/whatever named foo - which packages contain foo?"* and it seems that apt-file seems to do everything apt-cache does, but better - it reports more packages (apt-cache MISSES some), and it also shows the filenames involved.

Comment: They perform two completely separate tasks. The `apt-cache search` function is looking for **packages** within repositories. `apt-file find` is looking for **files** within your currently installed packages.

Comment: I think that both apt-cache and apt-file don't look at the currently installed packages - they look at all of them. As you can see in the cmd above, apt-file in fact reported MORE matches than apt-cache (and I definitely don't have "fish" installed) - hence my question, about why one would prefer apt-cache instead of apt-file.

Comment: That depends on how the apt-file cache was built. By default it only builds a cache of packages that are installed. It has other options that lets it get contents from apt-sources.

Comment: I installed it (with "apt-get install apt-file") and then used "apt-file update". I used no custom options... and the manpage for update says: "Resynchronize  the  package  contents from their sources. The lists of the contents of packages are fetched from the locations specified in /etc/apt/sources.list".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`apt-cache` queries a database of available packages and their metadata (installation source, version, dependencies, description, etc.).

`apt-file` queries a database of available packages and the files they contain.

The only information in common between these databases is that they both list available package names.

Comment: The reason I am asking is because apt-file reported MORE packages than apt-cache. I only used apt-cache for the use case "I need tool/manpage/whatever named foo - which packages contain foo?" and it seems that apt-file seems to do everything apt-cache does, but better - it reports more packages (apt-cache MISSES some), and it also shows the filenames involved.

Comment: @ttsiodras `apt-cache search` searches package names and descriptions. `apt-file search` searches the list of file names. So if you're looking for the package containing a command with a certain name, `apt-file` has the information. If you're looking for a package about a certain topic, `apt-cache` has the information.

Comment: Thanks, since I am always looking for packages based on contained files, indeed I was using the wrong tool. `apt-file` from now on!